# How to test React Router V6 Outlet using @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, testing-library

I have a component that I am using in React Router v6 for managing private routes, that does some checks on an auth token, and will either render the `Outlet` component or will redirect to a login page.

I have -

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const CheckAuth = (props) => {
  const valid = ...;
  if (!valid) {
    window.location.replace(loginUrl);
    return null;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

and using it like -

```
<Route element={<CheckAuth token={authToken} />}>
   // ... private routes ...
</Route>
```

I can mock out `window.location.replace` with Jest

```
delete window.location;
window.location = { replace: jest.fn() };
...
render(<CheckAuth token={token} />)
expect(window.location.replace).toHaveBeenCalledWith(loginUrl);
```

but how can I test the `Outlet` component using Testing Library?

Comment: Unrelated, why are you using `window.location`? You probably want to render a redirect, i.e. `<Navigate to={loginUrl} replace />` instead of mutating the location.

Comment: It's an external URL which I believe react-router doesn't handle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it helps anyone, I ended up just wrapping the components in the test with a react router components, and passed a dummy component as a child to Route and asserted that some fake text in that component was or was not rendered

Outside the test block -

```
const FakeComponent = () => <div>fake text</div>;
```

and for a *failure* scenario, where the outlet should not render -

```
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<CheckAuth />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<FakeComponent />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.queryByText('fake text')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

and for a *success* scenario, assert that the text is present -

```
render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<CheckAuth token={correctToken}/>}>
            <Route path="/" element={<FakeComponent />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.queryByText('fake text')).toBeInTheDocument();
```