# How to test routing logic with React Router v6 and testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I migrated from React Router v5 to v6 following this [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial). I want to test it with [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/), but my old unit tests (using the pattern in [this doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/)) stopped working.

My app with React Router v6 is like this

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: (
            <>
                <SiteHeader />
                <Outlet />
            </>
        ),
        errorElement: <NotFound />,
        children: [
            { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
            { path: "/posts", element: <Posts /> },
            { path: "/post/:postId", element: <PostPage /> },
        ],
    },
]);

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, it's using `RouterProvider` instead of `Switch`/`Route` (so I'm confused that this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654872/how-to-test-react-router-v6-outlet-using-testing-library-react) says it's using React Router v6 but it looks so different.).

[The code in official doc of testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/) is not using `RouterProvider` either.

I want to test some routing logic like this pseudo code:

```
renderWithRouter(<App />, "/posts"); // loads /posts page initially
await user.click(screen.getByText("some post title")); // trigger click
expect(getUrl(location)).toEqual("/post/123"); // checks the URL changed correctly
```

**How can I create a `renderWithRouter` function like [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/#reducing-boilerplate) with `RouterProvider`?** Note that [this `renderWithRouter`](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/#reducing-boilerplate) worked for me when I used React Router v5, but after migrating to v6, it stopped working.

My current dependency versions:

- "react": "^18.2.0",
- "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
- "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
- "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
- "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
- "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",

---

I tried this

```
test("click post goes to /post/:postId", async () => {
    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/posts"]}>
            <App />
        </MemoryRouter>,
    );
    // ...
});
```

but I got error

```
You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.

      31 | test("click post goes to /post/:postId", async () => {
    > 32 |     render(
         |     ^
      34 |         <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/posts"]}>
      36 |             <App />
```

Comment: What are you trying to ***unit*** test? You should be testing units ***of your code***, not 3rd-party code. What is there to stop you from wrapping the `Posts` component in a `MemoryRouter` and testing `Posts` behavior, as an example?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated. Please see the pseudo code part for what I want to test. I got error message when using `MemoryRouter` (see the end)

Comment: I don't think you are thinking of a "unit" correctly, as in testing the smallest ***unit*** of code necessary. If you are trying to test the `Post` component, then try rendering only `Post`. Again, it depends on what you are trying to unit test. Sometimes *some* components need to be rendered within a routing context, so a router is necessary to provide the context.

Comment: FWIW a test for navigating from one page to another isn't a unit test, this borders more on integration testing (*i.e. how two or more units of code integrate together*). `react-testing-library` isn't the correct tool for the job of integration testing. For this look for something like puppeteer, selenium, cypress, etc.

Comment: @DrewReese I do think this is a kind of unit test -- testing just the routing logic. See [this doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/#reducing-boilerplate) which is testing /home to /about page navigation. 
Unit testing clicking a button to open a panel is not so different from unit testing clicking a link to navigate to a different page.

Besides, my unit test worked for React Router V5 following [this doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/#reducing-boilerplate). It just broke after migrating to V6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to test your routes configuration as a whole, using the new `react-router-dom@6.4` Data Routers, then I'd suggest a bit of a refactor of the code to allow being able to stub in a `MemoryRouter` for any unit testing.

Declare the routes configuration on its own and export.

```
const routesConfig = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <>
        <SiteHeader />
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    errorElement: <NotFound />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
      { path: "/posts", element: <Posts /> },
      { path: "/post/:postId", element: <PostPage /> },
    ],
  },
];

export default routesConfig;
```

In the app code import `routesConfig` and instantiate the `BrowserRouter` the app uses.

```
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import routesConfig from '../routes';

const router = createBrowserRouter(routesConfig);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For unit tests import the `routesConfig` and instantiate a [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router).

```
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createMemoryRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import routesConfig from '../routes';

...

test("click post goes to /post/:postId", async () => {
  const router = createMemoryRouter(routesConfig, {
    initialEntries: ["/posts"],
  });

  render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);

  // make assertions, await changes, etc...
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! This works! With MemoryRouter, I need to use `router.state.location` when I want to check the current pathname or search.

Comment: BTW, https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router should probably be updated with this. :D

Comment: What about integration tests ?

Comment: MemoryRouter is a good choice ?

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Ah, I suppose it depends on the testing environment. Integration tests can oftentimes run in an actual browser context, e.g. Puppeteer, Selenium, Cypress, etc., then you could use the same router the app uses. If the test environment is still a Node.js env or non-browser env, then the `MemoryRouter` will still be useful.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I created my own `renderWithRouter` for React Router V6.

```
export const renderWithRouter = (route = "/") => {
    window.history.pushState({}, "Test page", route);
    return {
        user: userEvent.setup(),
        ...render(<RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} />),
    };
};
```

And this is an example test.

```
test("click Posts => shows Posts page", async () => {
    const { user } = renderWithRouter();
    const postsLink = screen.getByText("Posts").closest("a");
    expect(postsLink).not.toHaveClass("active");
    await user.click(postsLink as HTMLAnchorElement);
    expect(postsLink).toHaveClass("active");
    expect(getUrl(location)).toEqual("/posts");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from @Drew's answer)

My idea is to test a piece of UI component, so I don't want to pass a full route config(I thought about performance). I just used a straightforward route config for each test file.

```
const router = createMemoryRouter([{ path: '/', element: <MyComponent /> }]);

test('should render MyComponent', () => {
  render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);

  //   assertions
});
```

I ended up creating the `renderWithRouter` method like this

```
export const renderWithRouter = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  path = '/',
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>
) => {
  const { pathname } = new URL(`http://www.test.com${path}`);

  const router = createMemoryRouter(
    [{ path: pathname, element: <Providers>{ui}</Providers> }],
    { initialEntries: [path] }
  );

  return render(<RouterProvider router={router} />, { ...options });
};
```

Usage

```
renderWithRouter(<MyCompoent />);

// to assert search params
renderWithRouter(<MyCompoent />, '/user?user=1234');
```